# How to migrate from Neo4j Community to Enterprise edition (on Ubuntu)?

Tags: neo4j

I'm currently running **Neo4j Community edition, and would like to upgrade to the Enterprise edition.**

What is the best way to do this?

---

I have installed the Enterprise edition with:

```
sudo apt-get install neo4j-enterprise
```

But when I run...

```
sudo neo4j start
```

...I believe I am still running the community edition.

I couldn't find any instructions on how to migrate on the Neo4j website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Take a dump of your database (neo4j-admin dump)
2. Remove the neo4j installation (sudo apt-get remove neo4j)
3. Install neo4j-enterprise (sudo apt-get install neo4j-enterprise)
4. Load the database (neo4j-admin load)

Do not combine the two installations together (as you have been doing).

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, what do the commands `neo4j-admin dump` and `neo4j-admin load` do? Is this a form of backing up the database?

Comment: It's an offline dump into one file of the whole database. The CE does not have the backup functionality so using a dump is the only option.

Comment: What about the config files and plugins? This response comes up on Google as the first one, but if the users follow your instructions they'll just lose all their settings. Also, users need to be set up differently in the enterprise edition.